# Getting argument error when fetching data from API and decoding with Poison

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison, httpoison

I am new to Elixir/Phoenix and trying to learn by building a small app.

I am fetching data from a 3rd party API and keep getting the following error.

```
(ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.iolist_to_binary([%{"24h_volume" => "1000", "name" => "some_name"},{...}])
```

What I have in my controller is:

```
HTTPoison.start

%HTTPoison.Response{body: body} = HTTPoison.get!(url)
body = body
       |> Poison.decode!(keys: :atoms!)
```

This does not work. I have used (keys: :atoms) which is discouraged in the Poison documentation.

Here is my schema:

```
schema "things" do
  field :name, :string
  field :volume_24h, :float

  timestamps()
end

@doc false
def changeset(%Thing{} = thing, attrs) do
  thing
  |> cast(attrs, [:volume_24h, :name])
  |> validate_not_nil([:volume_24h, :name])
end

def validate_not_nil(changeset, fields) do
  Enum.reduce(fields, changeset, fn field, changeset ->
    if get_field(changeset, field) == nil do
      add_error(changeset, field, "nil")
    else
      changeset
    end
  end)
end
```

I am trying to use a different field name for "24h_volume" and I get this error:

```
(ArgumentError) argument error :erlang.binary_to_existing_atom("24h_volume", :utf8)
```

I am clearly missing something here.

Is there a way to pass the desired field name to Poison because "24h_volume" will not be a valid atom?
How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mess with `volume_24h` parameter.

As it is stated in [`Poison` documentation](https://github.com/devinus/poison#parser):

> Note that `keys: :atoms!` reuses existing atoms, i.e. if `:name` was not allocated before the call, you will encounter an argument error message.

This is exactly what happens. The application expects the `:volume_24h` key to come from the request, but it (for some reason, possibly due to a form misconfiguration of like) receives `24h_volume`. By using the permissive `atoms` call instead of `atoms!` you did not solve anything, you *have the issue hidden*. What actually happens, `24h_volume` key comes and *is being effectively discarded* by the call to `cast`.

What you need is either to fix the fronend/request sender to send `volume_24h` key, or to fix the controller to accept `:"24h_volume"` key.

---

There are two reasons behind discouraging `atoms` usage. The one is described in the `Poison` documentation: so called “atoms DOS attack” is possible with the random requests having random keys being issued subsequently, overflowing the atom storage. The second is that by using banged version `atoms!` one protects themselves from typos/misconfiguration like the one above.

FWIW, the atom for the proper key is being allocated in schema definition.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.
 I did not know I could use :"24h_volume" that is why I set :volume_24h in my migration file and wanted to change the key i was getting from Poison.

I was wondering if there was something like e.g.
Poison.decode!(things, keys: :atoms!, fields: {volume_24h: "24h_volume"})

Comment: I am pretty sure there is not. This transformation has nothing to do with json encoding and I doubt there are meaningful use cases for it.

Answer (score 2):

You have yo define your atom as follows because your atom normally is illegal to start with a number, but you can go around that by wrapping it with `"`

So change your atom as follows:

```
:"24_volume"
```

Comment: This statement is itself correct, but it has nothing to do with the issue. Check my answer for the correct explanation.

Comment: Yes, I had seen that an atom can not start with a number and I totally missed this :"string"
This is clearly a correct answer but being new to this elixir stuff
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa 's answer is more informative. 
Thank you!

Comment: @mudasobwa, I see. I thought that the json that he is getting was because the json that he was receiving.

Comment: @alexts glad you found your answer that you were looking for!